# Getting error when trying to declare custom cookie for Apache load balancer

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session, cookies

I have followed a number of tutorials (such as http://www.markround.com/archives/33-Apache-mod_proxy-balancing-with-PHP-sticky-sessions.html/) and have set up an Apache load balancer that is working fine except for session sustenance.

I am trying to modify my redirect (which works until I add the extra flag(?):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php - [CO=JSESSIONID:balancer.view-a:.ea-hq.com]
```

This causes an internal server error:

```
C:/Web Server/Apache24/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

So my sessions aren't being kept between the two servers.

I am using Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.5.11 on Windows server 2013.

How can I fix this?

If you need me to provide more details please say so.

---

I have made the change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [CO=JSESSIONID:balancer.view-a:.ea-hq.com]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php
```

But now many files don't load and have a status of 302 "Found" and are blank when viewing them through the inspector in Chrome.

---

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php [CO=JSESSIONID:balancer.view-a:.ea-hq.com]
```

Gives me the same result.

---

Here is my full .htaccess file without the cookie modification:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|swf|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Ignore rule if the real path exists, use that instead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Only use the filename and extension.
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)*([^.]+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|eot|woff|ttf|svg))$ public_html/images/$1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/importers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php

# Use below when apache is upgraded.
#FallbackResource public_html/index.php

#php_flag session.bug_compat_42 1
#php_flag session.bug_compat_warn 0


<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: While I guess this is programming of a sort, you might have better luck finding an answer on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

RewriteRule requires 2 or 3 parameters, your command has 4 parameters

the right syntax is

- **Command:** RewriteRule
- **Pattern:** ^(.*)$
- **Substitution:** -
- **Flags:** [CO=JSESSIONID:balancer.view-a:.ea-hq.com]

The error is related simply a matter of syntax, specifying the substitution is public_html/index.php and a - (dash).

(from the docs) A dash (-) indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag needs to be applied without changing the path.

So I think you only need a dash and not public_html/index.php (you can write other rules apart).

example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/index.php/$1 [L,CO=JSESSIONID:balancer.view-a:.ea-hq.com]
```

look the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for more info

Comment: I have made the changes but now the majority of my files (css etc) aren't being loaded properly and have a status of 302 "Found".

Comment: have you tried to use a single rule?
 `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php [CO=JSESSIONID:balancer.view-a:.ea-hq.com]`

Comment: @arino Di Clemente Yes, I get the same result :(

Comment: I think the problem is related to rewrite rules and isn't about the cookie flag that works well with that rule.

here's the doc about rules http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html
 
I suggest you proceed step by step, it begins to create the rewrite rule that interests you and when it works add to that inherent cookies

Comment: i've changed the answer

Comment: It still doesn't work :(. Still getting a redirect loop.